# Accessing ViewModel MutableState from unit tests' Dispatcher?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mutable

I am using MutableStates in the ViewModel for Compose

```
var desiredDate: MutableState<Date?> = mutableStateOf(null)
```

and additionally I want to receive changes of the state *inside* the model

```
    snapshotFlow { desiredDate.value }
            .onEach { updateConfirmationState() }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

and this works quite fine as productive code. Now I want to test updating one state causes update of other in unit tests. I am using classical MainCoroutineRule to override the Dispatchers.Main.

Now each snapshotFlow launch happens in a separate worker and since the MutableState is not shared, all the values are null.

There should be a way to test it in this way, right?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just started testing my compose view models and came across [this](https://proandroiddev.com/viewmodels-using-compose-mutablestateflows-or-mutablestates-64d34ba548c5) article.

> snapshotFlow relies on snapshots, a new value is emitted when a new snapshot is applied and not just when a value changes. In the production code Compose manages all the snapshots under the hood

So here's how I am testing this viewmodel:

```
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    userRepository: UserRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _user = userRepository.getMe()
    private var _selectedAvatar by mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
    val state = combine(
        _user,
        snapshotFlow { _selectedAvatar },
    ) { user, selectedAvatar ->
        SettingsUiState(selectedAvatar ?: user?.avatar)
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(2_000),
        initialValue = SettingsUiState()
    )

    fun updateAvatar(imageUrl: String?) {
        _selectedAvatar = imageUrl
    }
}

data class SettingsUiState(
    val avatar: Any? = null
}
```

And in the actual test:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class SettingsViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    val mockkRule = MockKRule(this)

    @get:Rule
    val dispatcherRule = TestDispatcherRule()

    @MockK
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    lateinit var viewModel: SettingsViewModel

    @Test
    fun `state returns updated SettingsUiState when selectedAvatar updates`() = runTest {
        val selectedAvatar = "http://www.example.com/2.jpg"
        val user = User(1, "John", "http://www.example.com/1.jpg")

        every { userRepository.getMe() } returns flowOf(user)

        viewModel = SettingsViewModel(userRepository)

        viewModel.state.test {
            assertEquals(SettingsUiState(user.avatar), awaitItem())

            withMutableSnapshot { viewModel.updateAvatar(selectedAvatar) }
            assertEquals(SettingsUiState(selectedAvatar), awaitItem())
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I am calling `updateAvatar(..)` inside the `.test`, Turbine has a [reference](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine#order-of-execution--shared-flows) on how to test shared flows.

Also, if you don't already have something like `TestDispatcherRule` in your project, here's a [sample](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-add-repository#9).